# How to get text value of a tag link in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get the text value of a HTML a link dynamically stored in PHP variable like

```
$term = '<a href="http://domain.ca/type/meat/" rel="tag">Meat</a>';
```

so the result will be `Meat` only. How can I do this?

Comment: See this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/. it took 10 seconds.

Comment: @u_mulder I dont think the OP ever mentioned using wordpress or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You could strip all tags from the text using `strip_tags`

```
 echo strip_tags($term);
```

echoes: Meat

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php